# "what an oyster is to a butter mushroom", meaning?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

> I don't know what an oyster is to a butter mushroom looking at your stall.

Does it mean that I can't tell the difference between an oyster and a butter mushroom?

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: looking at your stall. This is the context.

Comment: What is the stall? Who is saying it?

Comment: The customer is saying it.

Comment: On this site, we don't treat casual talk too seriously. If someone makes a small slip of the tongue, uses slang or foul language, or uses English incorrectly, that is a passing moment and not an educational moment. The oyster comment is a good example of someone asking something some time, and it made sense then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both a type of mushroom. See [oyster mushroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleurotus_ostreatus) and [butter mushroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyriboletus_appendiculatus).

The vendor has butter mushrooms and oyster mushrooms on the stall, and perhaps the buyer does not know the difference.

> I don't know what an oyster [mushroom] is to a butter mushroom looking at your stall.

Actual oysters would probably be on the seafood merchant's stand.

Comment: Yes. The buyer can't tell the difference, but precisely from linguistical view, should it be what an oyster mush room related to or compared with a butter mushroom?

Comment: It does mean what you supposed, but not quite in the same way.

Comment: It looks like a mistake to me. I would expect _what an oyster is from a butter mushroom_, with _from_ non-standard but sometimes used in this way. (I also wonder about _butter mushroom_. I cannot find this in any reference on the web except for the caption of an photo in the Wikipedia article on [Lithuanian cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_cuisine); but neither the text of that article, nor the article on Sullius brevipes, used that phrase. The article linked above calls it "butter bolete", but does not list "butter mushroom". )